# How to do salesforce authentication (pages) from ASP.Net MVC application login page using OAuth?

Tags: oauth, salesforce, integration, salesforce-service-cloud

We have the requirement like to do sales force authentication from ASP.Net MVC application login page directly using OAuth (authentication) protocol.

Can anyone help me how to do this one?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can start with checking out these Salesforce docs:

- [Using OAuth to Authorize External Applications](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_OAuth_to_Authorize_External_Applications)
- [Create a Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_create.htm&type=0)
- [Step Two: Set Up Authorization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm)

Comment: thank you. if you same type of example please share with me. Email : jitu.shewale@rediffmail.com